# Присваивание метода Complex в переменную double

Tags: c#

Прямоугольный импульс построен

```
  public static double calcimpuls(double U,double T,double x)
       {
           if (x >= 0 && x <= T)
               return U;
           else
               return 0;
        }
```

После в дело приступает прямое преобразование Фурье

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В формуле я вызываю результат построенного прямоугольного импульса в формулу прямого преобразования Фурье(Учитывая сложность интегрирования,применяется формула Эйлера)
Таким образом я получаю спектральную плотность

```
public static Complex GetSpectralDensity(double U, double frequency, double T,double x)
        {
            NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
            double f = 1 / T;
            double w = 2 * Math.PI * f;          
            return calcimpuls(U, T, x) * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Cos(w * t), 0, T) - Complex.ImaginaryOne * calcimpuls(U, T, x) * integration.Calculate(t=>Math.Sin(w*t),0,T);
        }
```

Из теории спектральная плотность амплитуд – это модуль комплексной спектральной плотности, поэтому

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Учитывая, что график ниже очень похож на график y=sin*x/x,но без отрицательных координат,то выполняю такой код(модуль,чтобы не было отрицательных чисел)

```
public static double GetSinModul(double U, double frequency, double T)
            {
                double x7 = GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T, 1);------   Неявное преобразование типа "System.Numerics.Complex" в "double" невозможно 

                return U *T * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(x7) / x7); 
            }
```

Результатом должен получится  такой график

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в преобразовании System.Numerics.Complex и double.

Я решил что будет лучше присвоить результат выполнения метода GetSpectralDensity  в переменную x7,для дальнейшего расчёта.
Но проблема в преобразовании так и осталась.Неявное преобразование типа "System.Numerics.Complex" в "double" невозможно

Формула с мнимой единицей и поэтому метод будет Complex и никак не double.
И компилятор не даст сделать это.

Comment: «Проблема в преобразовании System.Numerics.Complex и double.» — какая конкретно проблема?

Comment: Ага, теперь понятнее. Ну так проблема очевидна: у вас `GetSpectralDensity` возвращает `Complex`. Компилятор не знает, как получить из него `double`. Взять `X`, отбросить `Y`? Взять `Y`, отбросить `X`? Взять `R`? Как вы хотите? Компилятор за вас не преобразует сам.

Comment: Если спектральная плотность амплитуд - это модуль комплексной плотности, то и возьмите модуль от результата: `GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T, 1).Magnitude`

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась таким образом:
1)Создал список,выгрузил значения метода GetSpectralDensity
2)С помощью ForEach с каждого комплексного числа взял действительную часть числа и присвоил в переменную x2

```
 public static double GetSinModul(double U, double frequency, double T)
            {
                double x2=0;
                List<Complex> value = new List<Complex>();
                value.Add(GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T, 1));
                value.ForEach(x1=>x2=x1.Real);//Real
                 return x2 * T * Math.Sin(GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T, 1).Magnitude) / GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T, 1).Magnitude;
            }
```

Проблема с неявным преобразованием решена.
Спасибо!